# How to make button style with xml definition shown correct on real android device instead of emulator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

Following code run correct on emulator. But wrong on real device.

I have 3 xml files for corresponding button status: button_default.xml\button_pressed.xml\button_selected.xml. Here is one of them. Others are same with it except for colors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
         <solid android:color="#FF484747" />
         <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="5px"
            android:topRightRadius="5px"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5px"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5px" />
      </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:top="1px" android:bottom="1px" android:left="1px" android:right="1px">
     <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#FF484747" android:endColor="#FF000000" 
            android:type="linear" android:angle="270"
            android:centerX="0.5" android:centerY="0.5" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="5px"
            android:topRightRadius="5px"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5px"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5px" />
      </shape>
   </item>  
</layer-list>
```

Then I wrote button.xml as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

Last is the styles.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="button" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is the view on emulator(it's same on emulator 2.3 and 4.0):
(I can't upload image now. you can find it here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVtd9.jpg)

But it will be a **yellow background** button when I install the *.apk to my android pad(with android 2.3).

Anyone can provide me any direction to solve it? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I finally resolve it. I renamed button.xml to defaultbutton.xml. And modify styles.xml "<item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>"
 to "<item name="android:background">@drawable/defaultbutton</item>". Then it works. I guess android doesn't clear all resourse files when remove apps. (Previous styles file is yellow background.)

Comment: Anyway. Thanks sfratini \ alex!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your button is getting Highlighted? Does your emulator have the same specs as your phone? (Touchscreen specially)

Try adding another one into your Activity (If you only have one) and play with it.

Comment: THX, sfratini.I have drawable-hdpi\drawable-mdpi\drawable-ldpi in my app. there are 3 copies in those folder:)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector has the state "android:state_focused" which defines the color of the button when the button has a focus on it. Try to use "android:state_selected" and see if it helps.

Btw, I would recommend to replace all the "5px" in your xml files to "5dp" to make it suitable for different screen densities.